# Flatten JSON columns in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to do machine learning project on MyFitnessPal dataset
[dataset_kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zvikinozadze/myfitnesspal-dataset)

I tried to decrypt JSON format and then get all the key value pairs as columns and the rows.

but I can't transform keys to dataset columns

is there any effective way to handle it?

thank you in advance.

```
def extract_json(json_str):
    json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
    return json_dict

df['aggregate_intake_goal'] = df['aggregate_intake_goal'].apply(extract_json)
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data = df['aggregate_intake_goal'],record_path=['total'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the json_normalize action for this.

```
df_norm = pd.json_normalize(df['aggregate_intake_goal'].apply(json.loads))

df = pd.concat([df, df_norm], axis=1)

df = df.transpose().reset_index()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html